# Must all solutions of the given partial differential equation be of a certain form relating to another equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, transformation

I am stuck on the last part of a problem regarding the following three differential equations:

$$(1)\; u(x,y), \;
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y} + u = 0
\end{equation},\;x,y\gt 0$$
$$(2) \; F(s), \;
\begin{equation}
\frac{d F}{d s^2} + \frac{1}{s}\frac{d F}{d s}+F= 0
\end{equation}$$
$$(3) \; u(z,t), \;
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + u = 0
\end{equation},\;z\gt\lvert t\rvert$$

I have shown firstly that $u(x,y)=F(s)$ where $s=2\sqrt{xy}$, is a solution of $(1)$ provided $F(s)$ solves $(2)$.

I have also shown that $(3)$ is equivalent to $(2)$ with an appropriate transformation $x=az+bt,y=cz+dt$, and in that case, a solution is given by
$$u(z,t)=F(\sqrt{z^2-t^2})$$
for all $F$ solving $(2).$

The last part of the question says:

> Must all solutions have this form? Justify your answer.

I am a bit confused of what the question is asking me. I think it is saying 'can we find a solution to $(3)$ that, when transformed to $(x,y)$, is not a function of $2\sqrt{xy}$?' (or at least this is a sufficient condition for contradiction?).

If so, would I be right in saying that since $\sin(x+y)$ clearly solves $(1)$, and it is not a function of $2\sqrt{xy}$, we have found a solution without the given form? How could I show rigorously that it cannot be written as a function of $2\sqrt{xy}$?

I would be really appreciative for any feedback, thank you!

Comment: Any function $f(u,v)=\int_{I\subset \mathbb{R}}\mathrm{d}\rho\:C(\rho)\:e^{\rho u-\rho^{-1}v}$, with $C(\rho)$ *any* function and $I$ *any* subset of the line with non-zero measure, satisfies your first equation. For $\sin(x+y)$ and several functions of $\sqrt{xy}$  you can easily find the $C(\rho)$ and $I$ that yields such solutions.

Comment: (continuation) For instance, $f(u,v)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\rho/\sqrt{\rho}\:e^{\rho u+v/\rho}=e^{-2\sqrt{uv}}/\sqrt{v}$ is a solution and $f(u,v)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\rho/(2\rho)\:e^{\rho u+v/\rho}=K_0(2\sqrt{uv})$, with $K_0$ the modifies Bessel function.

Comment: I would restate your interpretation as "is there a solution which is not a function of $2\sqrt{xy}$"? Then the strategy for proof is obvious - for $\sin(x+y)$ find two values of $(x,y)$ which have the same value of $2\sqrt{xy}$ and different values of $\sin(x+y)$.

Comment: @DanielKatzner though it may be beyond the scope of my course, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @preferred_anon Ah OK thank you very much for that!

Comment: @jaycneek, I'm also interested in these sets of equations, in which book did you find them ?

Comment: @DanielKatzner The question is from a first year undergrad past paper at my university, the equations have not been formally introduced yet but I presume Bessel's equation will come up in some respect later

Comment: @jaycneek which paper ?

Comment: @DanielKatzner Oxford Prelims 2017 Resit M3 Q3